# mongoid: slice results to join documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Say I have 10 mongo documents, I want to be able to get them 2 at a time. So did each_slice which is ruby:

```
Twitter.limit(10).each_slice(2)
```

And I get a nice 5 element array with two arrays in each element.

What I am looking for is to join documents so I'll get 5 element array with two documents in each element and not two arrays.

Thanks!

Comment: MongoDB works with documents in a [cursor over query results](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Cursor.html). If you want to do fancier grouping of the results into pairs, this is best done in Ruby code (i.e. as you are already doing).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way :

```
 Twitter.limit(10).each_slice(2).map{|a| a.join(",") }
```

I used `,` as joining operator. But you can use any character you want to be there.

Example :

```
a = %w(doc1 doc2 doc3 doc4)
a.each_slice(2).map{|a| a.join(",") }
# => ["doc1,doc2", "doc3,doc4"]
```

Comment: Thank you. But each_slice is a ruby implementation, shouldn't I use Mongo to do this? Wouldn't it be a better approach?

Comment: @bymannan I don't know about *Mongo*.. Only Ruby... Then you wait, someone must will give you your desired answer..